# Postman not getting connected with localhost

Tags: postman, robo3t

I am using  Mern Stack as my backend. Everything was working fine until I typed "signin" part in "auth.js" but now postman is not able to connect with localhost. Even I used debugger to find out errors but nothing is shown. I am newbie in mern, so not able to figure out what's going wrong here. I even Tried turning off ssl certification in postman.

Postman Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCrl8.png

VS code Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUxwz.png

Here are the codes:

auth.js (routes)

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator');
const {signout,signup, signin} = require("../controllers/auth");

router.post(
    "/signup",
    [
    check("name","name should be atleast 3 char").isLength({ min: 3 }),
    check("email","email is required").isEmail(),
    check("password","password should be at least 3 char").isLength({min:3})
],signup);

router.post("/signin",[

    check("email","email is required").isEmail(),
    check("password","password field is required").isLength({min:3})

],signin);


router.get("/signout", signout);


module.exports = router;
```

auth.js (controller)

```
const User = require("../models/user");
const { check, validationResult } = require("express-validator");
var jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
var expressJwt = require("express-jwt");

exports.signup = (req, res) => {
  const errors = validationResult(req);

  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(422).json({
      error: errors.array()[0].msg
    });
  }

  const user = new User(req.body);
  user.save((err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        err: "NOT able to save user in DB"
      });
    }
    res.json({
      name: user.name,
      email: user.email,
      id: user._id
    });
  });
};

exports.signin = (req, res) => {
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(422).json({
      error: errors.array()[0].msg
    });
  }

  User.findOne({ email }, (err, user) => {
    if (err || !user) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        error: "USER email does not exists"
      });
    }

    if (!user.autheticate(password)) {
      return res.status(401).json({
        error: "Email and password do not match"
      });
    }

    //create token
    const token = jwt.sign({ _id: user._id }, process.env.SECRET);

    //put token in cookie
    res.cookie("token", token, { expire: new Date() + 9999 });

    //send response to front end
    const { _id, name, email, role } = user;
    return res.json({ token, user: { _id, name, email, role } });
  });
};

exports.signout = (req, res) => {
  res.json({
    message: "User signout"
  });
};
```

app.js

```
require('dotenv').config();


const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const express = require("express")
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require ("body-parser");
const cookieParser = require ("cookie-parser");
const cors = require ("cors");

const authRoutes =require("./routes/auth");  

// DB connection
mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE,{
    useNewUrlParser:true,
    useUnifiedTopology:true,
    useCreateIndex:true
}).then(() => {
    console.log("DB CONNECTED")
});

// Middlewares
app.use(bodyParser.json()); 
app.use(cookieParser()); 
app.use(cors()); 


// My Routes
app.use("/api", authRoutes);


//PORT
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

app. listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`app is running at ${port}`);
} );
```

user.js

```
const mongoose = require ("mongoose");
const crypto = require('crypto');
const uuidv1 = require("uuid/v1");

  var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      name: {
          type: String,
          required:true,
          maxlength:32,
          trim:true
      },
          lastname: {
            type: String,
            maxlength:32,
            trim:true
        },
        email: {
            type: String,
            trim:true,
            required:true,
            unique:true
        },
           userinfo:{
               type:String,
               trim:true
           },
            encry_password:{
                type:String,
                required:true
            },
            salt: String,
            role:{
                type:Number,
                default:0
            }, 
            purchases : {
                type: Array,
                default:[]
            }
  },{timestamps:true});

userSchema.virtual("password")
.set(function(password){
    this._password= password;
    this.salt = uuidv1();
    this.encry_password = this.securePassword(password);
}) 
.get(function(){
    return this._password
})

  userSchema.methods = {
authenticate: function(plainpassword){
    return this.securePassword(plainpassword)=== this.encry_password
},

    securePassword: function(plainpassword){
        if(!plainpassword) return "";
        try{
            return crypto
            .createHmac('sha256', this.salt)
            .update(plainpassword)
            .digest('hex');
        }catch(err){
            return"";
        }
     }
  };

  module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema );
```

Comment: I think you are missing the express router part. How is it supposed to know if that is  a POST or GET endpoint?

Comment: I have mentioned that in auth.js (route)